# convert string to integer then add 1 with RubyMotion

Tags: rubymotion

Can someone tell me why the following code is wrong:

```
def pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow:row, inComponent:component)
@myLabel.text = "#{row+1}"  
end

def remain
@remainLabel.text = @myLabel.text
end

def left
remain.to_i (+1)
end
```

I'm calling the "left" method via a button click but I get "invalid radix 1" as an error. I have tried various different configurations including with and without the brackets and with and without spaces. Basically, whatever I do, I either get an error or else just the selected number from the picker without the 1 added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
remain.to_i + 1
```

The method `remain` returns a string, the string in `@myLabel.text`.  When you write:

```
remain.to_i (+1)
```

Ruby thinks you are passing the parameter `(+1)` to the `to_i` method.  It turns out that `to_i` does take a parameter which is the base (or radix) you want it to use to interpret the string.

```
puts "FF".to_i(16)  // prints "255"
puts "101".to_i(2)  // prints "5"
```

Base 1 is an invalid base hence the invalid radix message.  The default base is 10, so

```
puts "123".to_i(10)  // prints "123"
puts "123".to_i      // prints "123"
```

Comment: Oh right, no wonder I'm not getting what I want. This is back to the question you answered for me yesterday. Basically, I want to take the number selected via a picker and use that number in a calculation - in this case I want to add that number to a number that has been generated elsewhere in the code. In your last answer you said "use Ruby's to_i method to turn a string to an integer ...since your row number matches the label on that row, just use the row variable in didSelectRow since it is already an integer" so that is what I have tried, obviously incorrectly. Any further help please

Comment: You should have everything you need.  `remain.to_i` returns an integer. `left` returns that + 1 if you change it like I suggested on line 2 above.  Is there something you still don't understand?

Comment: In `pickerView(pickerView, didSelectRow:row, inComponent:component)`, the variable `row` is a integer and it matches the number from your picker.  You can use it right there in a calculation, or you can save that in an instance variable `@myPickedNumber = row` for use elsewhere in your class.